# Call python function with hotkey

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

I would like to call a python function or a python file to execute with a hotkey. My function is an infinite loop. I would like to terminate the execution as well with a hotkey. Is it possible?

Windows shortcuts is not an option, because I would like to choose 1 key to execute and not a combination of keys ( for example CRTL + SHIFT + L ) .

It would be nice if the hotkey would be the middle ( scroll ) button of the mouse.

Comment: Use wxPython to register a global hotkey. I don't know whether single key or mouse button can be assigned. But if not, you can write a key logger to do it. Or use external tool like autohotkey to communicate with your program. That is, if system wide hotkey is what you are asking about. Getting mouse, key, joystick, MIDI and other hardware events when your window is active is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a hotkey using the [mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/) module (`pip install mouse`). To run a function in a loop and then stop in on the hotkey again, you will need to create a new thread ([intro to threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)) that will run this loop. Then you will want to use an event to stop this thread's execution when the hotkey is pressed again. Below is an example of an implementation that does this.

```py
import mouse  # pip install mouse
import threading
import time

    
def your_function():
    # the function you want to execute in the loop
    print("Executing your function...")
    time.sleep(0.9)  # You will probably want to remove this

def repeat_function(kill_event):
    print("Starting loop...")
    while not kill_event.is_set():
        your_function()
    print("Exiting loop...")
    

while True:
    print("Waiting for hotkey press...")
    kill_event = threading.Event()
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: repeat_function(kill_event))

    # set the hotkey that will start the loop to middle mouse button click
    start_hook = mouse.on_middle_click(new_thread.start)
    mouse.wait(mouse.MIDDLE, mouse.UP)   # wait till the hotkey gets released
    mouse.unhook(start_hook)   # clear the old hotkey

    # set the hotkey to kill the loop instead
    end_hook = mouse.on_middle_click(kill_event.set)
    mouse.wait(mouse.MIDDLE, mouse.UP)
    new_thread.join()        # wait for thread to fully finish, unnecessary
    mouse.unhook(end_hook)   # remove kill hotkey and start again
```